# How to set and get session in magento2.2.3?

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.3

I have used below code to set the session in Observer file:

```
namespace VendorName\ModueleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ClassName implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->customerSession->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }
}
```

I want to access this session at **app/code/Magento/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php fetch()** action.

I use the below code:

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

$this->customerSession->getIpAddress();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This don't work ? If not, then maybe the event has not happened yet.

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

public function getValueFromObserver()
{
   return $this->customerSession->getIpAddress();
}
```